# Get a Json string from a public URL using php

Tags: php, json

Ok, i thinked i was able to do this easily but i cant figure how.
I have tried in many ways i found here and in other pages but nothing works; i spent two days with this, but i finally decided to register here and ask.

So here is my karma:

```
http://api.bitcoinvenezuela.com/DolarToday.php?json=yes
```

That url generates this json:

> {"_antibloqueo":{"mobile":"https://dt.wordssl.net","video":"","corto_alternativo":"https://bit.ly/venezuela911","enable_iads":"","enable_admobbanners":"ca-app-pub-8212448379596570/1946229161","enable_admobinterstitials":"","alternativo":"68747470733a2f2f64626d7a647431663034653531632e636c6f756466726f6e64742e6e6574","alternativo2":"68747470733a2f2f64626d7a647431663034653531632e636c6f756466726f6e64742e6e6574","notifications":"https://d3c134ru0r3b0g.cloudfront.net","resource_id":"33504 A"},"_labels":{"a":"DOLARTODAY","a1":"DOLAR CUCUTA","b":"IMPLICITO","c":"DICOM","d":"DOLAR BITCOIN","e":"DIPRO"},"_timestamp":{"epoch":"**1513837984**","fecha":"Diciembre 21, 2017 02:33 AM","fecha_corta":"Dic 21, 2017","fecha_corta2":"Dic 2017","fecha_nice":"Diciembre 21, 2017","dia":"Jueves","dia_corta":"Jue"},"USD":{"transferencia":**121205.72**,"transfer_cucuta":121205.72,"efectivo":10330.84,"efectivo_real":122608.7,"efectivo_cucuta":122608.7,"promedio":121205.72,"promedio_real":11311,"cencoex":10,"sicad1":94496.22,"sicad2":11311,"bitcoin_ref":94496.22,"localbitcoin_ref":94496.22,"dolartoday":121205.72},"EUR":{"transferencia":143581.51,"transfer_cucuta":143581.51,"efectivo":12259.61,"efectivo_real":145502.19,"efectivo_cucuta":145502.19,"promedio":143581.51,"promedio_real":13422.76,"cencoex":11.87,"sicad1":112138.66,"sicad2":13422.76,"dolartoday":143581.51},"COL":{"efectivo":0.023,"transfer":0.023,"compra":0.023,"venta":0.02},"GOLD":{"rate":1265.9},"USDVEF":{"rate":10.02959},"USDCOL":{"setfxsell":2820,"setfxbuy":2740,"rate":3606,"ratecash":2825,"ratetrm":3005.76,"trmfactor":0.2,"trmfactorcash":0.06},"EURUSD":{"rate":1.18672},"BCV":{"fecha":"1513569600","fecha_nice":"Diciembre 18, 2017","liquidez":"100.643.049.794","reservas":"9.742.000"},"MISC":{"petroleo":"56,14","reservas":"9,7"}}*

I need read the json it generates to get the bolded values (only 2 values i need from there); I have tried with curl, file_get_contents, and many other ways, but nothing works.

Basically, I can not understand WHY this code do not works:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://api.bitcoinvenezuela.com/DolarToday.php?json=yes'; 
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); 

echo $obj;  

?>
```

I get a warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.bitcoinvenezuela.com/DolarToday.php?json=yes): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/u704982448/public_html/lbapi.php on line 3

Any idea what is happening here? Where is the fail?

EDIT: Looks like the problem here is that my server ip is blocked. Any workaround for this?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: If your connection times out you may not have a direct connection to the remote host from your PHP server, is your server behind a firewall or proxy server maybe? (I guess the remote host is accessible from your browser if you enter that URL?)

Comment: Yes, i can access the url from my browser. Im using hostinger to host my web services. After maybe 100 different aproachs in the last 2 days, i found the file "dolartoday.json" on my server directory! I really dont know what i did to store it there, but something worked at least 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print an `array` in `echo` statement so its an error.

```
<?php 
    $url = 'http://api.bitcoinvenezuela.com/DolarToday.php?json=yes'; 
    $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($obj);
?>
```

Regarding `connection timeout` you need to check IP block etc

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.
I tested it on my webpage and it worked fine.
Just needed to replace echo with var_dump().

http://www.hoppvader.nu/Mail/test.php

```
$url = 'http://api.bitcoinvenezuela.com/DolarToday.php?json=yes'; 
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); 

var_dump($obj);
```

To echo the two values you need you use this code:

```
echo $obj["_timestamp"]["epoch"];
echo $obj["USD"]["transferencia"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the test and clarification to access the 2 data into the json. Looks like it is a problem with the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a connection problem on server side. Maybe there is some firewall configured or the server has no connection to the internet etc...

You should try the following, log in into server and try to run:

```
curl http://api.bitcoinvenezuela.com/DolarToday.php?json=yes
```

This command would basically try to reach the url and print the output.

If you have the same timeout issue here then you have the proof that the error is independent of your php script.

Comment: I tried it and i got nothing. Looks like the target web page blocked my server IP. Is any workaround for this? (I dont know if i need create a new answer)